# How to change from checkout on agent to checkout on server

Tags: svn, teamcity

I'm trying to set up a TeamCity server using a SVN repository and i got that working, but the problem is that whenever i make a change in the repository, i an "Error while applying patch". This is the complete error [svn: E200015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPskD.png)

```
Failed to perform checkout on agent: svn: E200015: Error during update from https: //laptop-eh7tmoiv/svn/TCRepoTest to C:\BuildAgent\work\2e2edba23560e7ef
```

I've read the whole [Checkout documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/VCS+Checkout+Mode) on jetbrains, but i can't find where to change the checkout way. I want to checkout on server side.

This is the build log.

```
[14:47:40]TeamCity server version is 2017.1.3 (build 46961)

[14:48:27]The build is removed from the queue to be prepared for the start

[14:48:27]Collecting changes in 1 VCS root

[14:48:27][Collecting changes in 1 VCS root] VCS Root details

[14:48:27][VCS Root details] "svn: https: //laptop-eh7tmoiv/svn/TCRepoTest" {instance id=1, parent internal id=1, parent id=TCRepoTest_SvnHttpsLaptopEh7tmoivSvnTCRepoTest, description: "svn: https: //laptop-eh7tmoiv/svn/TCRepoTest"}

[14:48:27][Collecting changes in 1 VCS root] Detecting changes in VCS root 'svn: https: //laptop-eh7tmoiv/svn/TCRepoTest' (used in 'BuildOne')

[14:48:27][Collecting changes in 1 VCS root] Will collect changes for 'svn: https: //laptop-eh7tmoiv/svn/TCRepoTest' starting from revision 13

[14:48:27][Collecting changes in 1 VCS root] Compute revision for 'svn: https: //laptop-eh7tmoiv/svn/TCRepoTest'

[14:48:27][Compute revision for 'svn: https: //laptop-eh7tmoiv/svn/TCRepoTest'] Upper limit revision: 13

[14:47:41][Compute revision for 'svn: https: //laptop-eh7tmoiv/svn/TCRepoTest'] MaxModId = 16

[14:48:27][Compute revision for 'svn: https: //laptop-eh7tmoiv/svn/TCRepoTest'] Latest commit attached to build configuration: 13

[14:48:27][Compute revision for 'svn: https: //laptop-eh7tmoiv/svn/TCRepoTest'] Computed revision: 13

[14:48:27]Starting the build on the agent W10Agent

[14:48:28]Agent time zone: America/Montevideo

[14:48:28]Agent is running under JRE: 1.8.0_121-b13

[14:48:28]Clearing temporary directory: C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp

[14:48:28]Publishing internal artifacts

[14:48:28][Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [WebPublisher]

[14:48:28][Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [ArtifactsCachePublisher]

[14:48:28]Will perform clean checkout. Reason: Checkout directory is empty or doesn't exist

[14:48:28]Checkout directory: C:\BuildAgent\work\2e2edba23560e7ef

[14:48:28]Updating sources: auto checkout (on agent)

[14:48:28][Updating sources] Will use agent side checkout

[14:48:28][Updating sources] VCS Root: svn: https: //laptop-eh7tmoiv/svn/TCRepoTest

[14:48:28][VCS Root: svn: https: //laptop-eh7tmoiv/svn/TCRepoTest] revision: 13

[14:48:28][VCS Root: svn: https: //laptop-eh7tmoiv/svn/TCRepoTest] Checkout from https: //laptop-eh7tmoiv/svn/TCRepoTest

[14:48:28][VCS Root: svn: https: //laptop-eh7tmoiv/svn/TCRepoTest] Using working copy format 1.8

[14:48:28][Updating sources] Failed to perform checkout on agent: svn: E200015: Error during update from https: //laptop-eh7tmoiv/svn/TCRepoTest to C:\BuildAgent\work\2e2edba23560e7ef

[14:48:28]Publishing internal artifacts

[14:48:28][Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [WebPublisher]

[14:48:28][Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [ArtifactsCachePublisher]

[14:48:28]Build failed to start. Artifacts will not be published for this build

[14:48:29]Build finished
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Based on the @Didier answer i was able to find where to configure the checkout mode.
You have to go to your project, then select a **Build Configuration**, then go to **Version Control Settings** on the left panel, show _advanced options_ and there is the checkout mode settings. 
Thanks again for the help, and sorry for asking such trivial questions, but i couldn't find the option anywhere.
You are helping a junior dev out! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Inside TeamCity, go to the specified configuration, on the top right corner: `edit settings`.

On the left, go to `vcs Settings`: On the top part of the scrren, you define the VCS your configuration will use, on the bottom, you can setup how to checkout sources. (agent side, server side)

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/VCS+Checkout+Mode

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I just can't seem to find those settings. I go to my project > edit project settings > VCS roots > edit vcs root ... but then i dont't have any option to select how i want to checkout. The only thing i have about checkout is this http://i.imgur.com/ogI99qQ.png
But i can't find any more options or selectors that show checkout mode.
I'm sorry if what i'm asking is a trivial question, but i'm learning hehe.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Found it. It's not on the project settings, it's on the build configuration settings. 
Thanks again!